# Wordpress get post order by custom category

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-post-type

I am getting custom post. How can i order them by custom category. My custom category name is 'weeks'.
These are my args.

```
$args = array(
                        'post_type' => $post_type,
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'caller_get_posts' => 1,
                        'orderby' => 'title',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                    );
```

I use orderby 'title'. But it did not work.

Comment: try order by `post_title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $args = array(
                    'post_type' => $post_type,
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    //'caller_get_posts' => 1, // use this option to ignore sticky posts, else you don't need to include this parameter
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'weeks',
                            ),
                    ),
                    'orderby' => 'post_title',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                );
```